# populating select tag after successfull login

Tags: struts2

I tried to populate the select tag after successful login but system gives the following error.
Following is the code.

Struts.xml

```
<package name="default" extends="struts-default">
    <action name="LoginAction" class="com.Struts2.Login.MDLogin">
        <result name="error">/Login/UILogin.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Login/UIRegister.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="RegisterAction" class="com.Struts2.Register.MDRegister">
        <result name="error">/Login/UIRegister.jsp</result>
        <result name="success">/Login/UIRegisterData.jsp</result>
    </action>
    <action name="populateAction" method="populatePosition"   class="com.Struts2.Register.MDRegister">
        <result name="populate">/Login/UIRegister.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

UIRegister.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s" %>    
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     >
<html>
<head>
<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="0;URL=populateAction.action">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1;">
<title>Register</title>
</head>
<body>
<center>
Register Client
</center>
<s:form action="/RegisterAction">
<s:textfield name="txtUser" maxLength="10" size="10" label="User Name"/>    
<s:password name="txtPassword" label="Password" maxlength="15" size="15"/>
<s:textarea name="txtAbout" label="About you" col="20" row="3"></s:textarea>
<s:checkbox name="chkUpdate" label="check for the update" fieldValue="true" /
<s:select name="cboSelect" list="cboSelectList" listKey="strKey" istValue="strValue"                          
    multiple="false" label="Position"/>
<s:submit value="submit"></s:submit>
</s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

MDSelect.java

```
package com.Struts2.Select;

public class MDSelect 
{
private String strKey;
private String strValue;


public String getStrKey() {
    return strKey;
}


public void setStrKey(String strKey) {
    this.strKey = strKey;
}


public String getStrValue() {
    return strValue;
}


public void setStrValue(String strValue) {
    this.strValue = strValue;
}


public MDSelect(String strMainKey,String strMainValue)
{
    this.strKey=strMainKey;
    this.strValue=strMainValue;
}

 }
```

MDRegister.java

```
 package com.Struts2.Register;

 import java.sql.SQLException;
 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Vector;

 import com.Struts2.Select.MDSelect;
 import com.Struts2.model.MDModel;
 import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;

 public class MDRegister extends ActionSupport 
 {
private String txtUser;
private String txtPassword;
private String txtAbout;
private String chkUpdate;
private String MDSelect;
private ArrayList<MDSelect> cboSelectList;
MDModel model=new MDModel();
public String getTxtUser() {
    return txtUser;
}

public void setTxtUser(String txtUser) {
    this.txtUser = txtUser;
}

public String getTxtPassword() {
    return txtPassword;
}

public void setTxtPassword(String txtPassword) {
    this.txtPassword = txtPassword;
}

public String getTxtAbout() {
    return txtAbout;
}

public void setTxtAbout(String txtAbout) {
    this.txtAbout = txtAbout;
}

public String getChkUpdate() {
    return chkUpdate;
}

public void setChkUpdate(String chkUpdate) {
    this.chkUpdate = chkUpdate;
}



public String getMDSelect() {
    return MDSelect;
}

public void setMDSelect(String mDSelect) {
    MDSelect = mDSelect;
}

public ArrayList<MDSelect> getCboSelectList() {
    return cboSelectList;
}

public void setCboSelectList(ArrayList<MDSelect> cboSelectList) {
    this.cboSelectList = cboSelectList;
}

public String populatePosition() throws SQLException
{
    Vector cboPosition=(Vector)model.cmbGCode("DPT");
     System.out.println("cboPosition>>>>>>>"+cboPosition.size());       
    cboSelectList=new ArrayList<MDSelect>();
    for(int iPos=0;iPos<cboPosition.size();iPos++)
    {
        Object[] objData=(Object[])cboPosition.elementAt(iPos);
        cboSelectList.add(new MDSelect(String.valueOf(objData[0]),        

                    String.valueOf(objData[1])));           
    }

    setCboSelectList(cboSelectList);
     System.out.println("In populate register 2 cboPosition>>>>>>>"+cboPosition.size());        
    return "populate";
}



public String execute()
{       
    if(getTxtUser().trim().equals(""))
    {
        addFieldError("txtUser", "User Can not be blank");
        return ERROR;
    }
    if(getTxtPassword().trim().equals(""))
    {
        addFieldError("txtPassword", "Password can not be blank");
        return ERROR;
    }
    if(getTxtAbout().trim().equals(""))
    {
        addFieldError("txtAbout", "Please tell us about your self");
        return ERROR;
    }

    return SUCCESS;
}
```

}

now when I successfully login into the system, it shows me the following error.

```
    HTTP Status 500 - tag 'select', field 'list', name 'cboSelect': The requested list  

    key 'cboSelectList' could not be resolved as a  
    collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type. Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]
```

---

```
 type Exception report

 message tag 'select', field 'list', name 'cboSelect': The requested list key 'cboSelectList' could not be resolved as a collection/array/map/enumeration/iterator type.   Example: people or people.{name} - [unknown location]

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.
```

Comment: May be because you have not specified that list `cboSelectedList` in your `execute` method in Your action class .. Try to define the list In execute method  ..

Answer (score 0):

There a couple of flaws in you application. **No method** is defined for `LoginAction` and `RegistrationAction`, So in that case the **execute()** method will be called for both actions!!

Is that the way you wanted?   And since you want to populate select after successful login, it too fails because you are not populating `cboSelectedList` in your execute(), you are bound to get error.

If you are new to struts get basics on struts right!